# How to set a default value which comes from querystring in Html.Dropdownlist for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to set a default value to the drop-down list where the default value comes from another page passed as a query string.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Products, new SelectList(Model.Products.Select(x => x.Name)),
                        "Select a Product",
                        new {@class = "product-form__selector", ID = "product-field", required = "required"})
```

Comment: you should set `FormInputs.SelectedServices` in the get action method which is called for this view

Comment: Generally, what you're doing should work. Do you receive an error message? What do you get as a result of your code vs. what you expect? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).